# jsf: conditionally rendered primefaces command buttons does not invoke backing bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces, commandbutton, conditional-rendering

I am using Primefaces components framework with Java Server Faces web application development. I faced this problem for past two days. When I click statistic input switch component that will render two `p:commandButton` after that click switch planning input that will render 5 `p:commandButton` these buttons aren't set action named variable of back bean despite update rendering work well. Please see below two pictures

[image]

buttons that aren't work

[image]

I am assume conditionally rendered components aren't connected back bean. Might be ajax rendered components not recognized entire application. I am using `f:setPropertyActionListener` for setting backing action bean variable.

```
    <p:tab title="#{lang['top_menu_statistic_planning']}">
        <p:ribbonGroup>
            <h:form>
                <div class="statistic-planning-switcher-parts">
                    <p:inputSwitch onLabel="Statistic" offLabel="Planning"
                        value="#{selectBooleanView.value2}">
                        <p:ajax listener="#{selectBooleanView.addMessage}"
                            update=":mainReportSubViewsRenderID :mainViewsRenderID" />
                    </p:inputSwitch>
                </div>
            </h:form>
        </p:ribbonGroup>
        <p:ribbonGroup label="">
            <h:panelGroup id="mainReportSubViewsRenderID">
                <h:panelGroup
                    rendered="#{selectBooleanView.addMessage() == 'Checked'}">
                    <p:commandButton value="Import-1" update=":mainViewsRenderID"
                        icon="ui-ribbonicon-zoomout" styleClass="ui-ribbon-bigbutton">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="report_statistic.import"
                            target="#{hometabmanager.action}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                    <p:commandButton value="Export" update=":mainViewsRenderID"
                        icon="fa fa-asterisk" styleClass="ui-ribbon-bigbutton">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="report_statistic.export"
                            target="#{hometabmanager.action}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                </h:panelGroup>
                <h:panelGroup
                    rendered="#{selectBooleanView.addMessage() == 'Unchecked'}">
                    <p:commandButton value="Button-1" update=":mainViewsRenderID"
                        icon="ui-ribbonicon-zoomin" styleClass="ui-ribbon-bigbutton">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="report_planning.section1"
                            target="#{hometabmanager.action}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                    <p:commandButton value="Button-2" update=":mainViewsRenderID"
                        icon="ui-ribbonicon-zoomin" styleClass="ui-ribbon-bigbutton">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="report_planning.section2"
                            target="#{hometabmanager.action}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                    <p:commandButton value="Button-3" update=":mainViewsRenderID"
                        icon="ui-ribbonicon-zoomout" styleClass="ui-ribbon-bigbutton">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="report_planning.section3"
                            target="#{hometabmanager.action}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                    <p:commandButton value="Button-4" update=":mainViewsRenderID"
                        icon="ui-ribbonicon-zoomin" styleClass="ui-ribbon-bigbutton">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="report_planning.section4"
                            target="#{hometabmanager.action}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                    <p:commandButton value="Button-5" update=":mainViewsRenderID"
                        icon="ui-ribbonicon-zoomout" styleClass="ui-ribbon-bigbutton">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="report_planning.section5"
                            target="#{hometabmanager.action}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </p:ribbonGroup>
    </p:tab>
```

---------above code renders on below panelgrid ----------------------------------

```
            <h:panelGroup
                rendered="#{hometabmanager.action == 'report_planning.section1'}">
                <ui:include src="/views/report/report_section1.xhtml" />
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:panelGroup
                rendered="#{hometabmanager.action == 'report_planning.section2'}">
                <ui:include src="/views/report/report_section2.xhtml" />
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:panelGroup
                rendered="#{hometabmanager.action == 'report_planning.section3'}">
                <ui:include src="/views/report/report_section3.xhtml" />
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:panelGroup
                rendered="#{hometabmanager.action == 'report_planning.section4'}">
                <ui:include src="/views/report/report_section4.xhtml" />
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:panelGroup
                rendered="#{hometabmanager.action == 'report_planning.section5'}">
                <ui:include src="/views/report/report_section5.xhtml" />
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:panelGroup
                rendered="#{hometabmanager.action == 'report_statistic.import' and selectBooleanView.subSectionPageBlock == 'block-statistic'}">
                <ui:include src="/views/report/report_import2.xhtml" />
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:panelGroup
                rendered="#{hometabmanager.action == 'report_statistic.export' and selectBooleanView.subSectionPageBlock == 'block-statistic'}">
                <ui:include src="/views/report/report_export.xhtml" />
            </h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: You need to put your XHTML code where these buttons are located and your backing been code that you're expecting to be executed

Comment: thank you for your first valuable comment, i am using Primefaces RibbonGroup and every button works good at first rendered when page load despite conditionally rendered component buttons aren't set its own value to backing bean.  yes I did, codes are placed each own proper place.